# log4j2 logs are not getting logged in auto generated log file under logs folder

Tags: java, logging, testng, log4j2, properties-file

Here i am trying to save my logs generated during execution in logs file i have used lo4j2.properties with Testng listener to save my logs , my log4j2.properties is as below

log4j2.properties

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/automationLogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.append=true

loggers=file
logger.file.name=Demo
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

TestListeners.java file file has following code

TestListeners.java

```
package Listners;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

import RecallAgreementPojo.RecallAgreementPayload;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import utils.ConvertJSON;


public class TestListeners implements ITestListener{

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TestListeners.class);
    Response  response = null;  
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {

        logger.info("********* Test started **********" + result.getName());

    }

    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        logger.info("********* Test Success **********");
    }

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        ITestContext context = result.getTestContext();
        response = (Response) context.getAttribute("Response");
        if(response != null)
            logger.error("********* Test Failed **********" + response.prettyPrint());

    }

    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {

        logger.warn("********* Test Skipped **********" + result.getName());

    }

    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
//      logger.warn("********* Test passed partially with  **********" + result.SUCCESS_PERCENTAGE_FAILURE);

    }

    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        logger.info("=========== onStart :-" + context.getName() + "===============");
    }

    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        logger.info("********* Test Completed **********" + context.getName());
        Map<String,List> newAgreementDetails =  (Map<String, List>) context.getAttribute("AgreementDetails");
        Map<String,RecallAgreementPayload> newAgreementsMap = (Map<String, RecallAgreementPayload>) context.getAttribute("AgreementRequests");
        for(Entry<String, List> entry : newAgreementDetails.entrySet()) {
            logger.info(entry.getKey() + " : " +  entry.getValue());
        }

        for(Entry<String, RecallAgreementPayload> entry : newAgreementsMap.entrySet()) {
            logger.info(entry.getKey() + " : " );
            ConvertJSON.JSONConverter(entry.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

However i am getting empty file as automationLogs.log

Comment: Your logger is called `Listners.TestListeners` (the FQCN of your class), while the name of your logger config is `Demo`. That is why your log file is empty: there are no messages sent by loggers, whose name is `Demo` or starts with `Demo.`. BTW: packages in Java are usually lowercase to distinguish them from classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logger in *log4j2.properties* is named `Demo`.

```
logger.file.name=Demo              <<-- logger name
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE    <<-- reference to the appender that will write to file
```

In order to write to the file, you will need to provide *LogManager* the logger's name (`Demo`) for the LogManager to use it. `LogManager.getLogger("<logger name>")`.

The appender `LOGFILE`, that logger `Demo` is referencing, will then write the logs to the file `automationLogs.log`.

In other words, change this:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TestListeners.class);
```

to this:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("Demo");
```

If this is not the behavior you are expecting, and are really more interested in passing the TestListeners.class to the LogManager, then perhaps using a RollingFile will be better suited for your needs.

Though I have not tested the below on your configs, this would be the idea:

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= ${filename}/automationLogs.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern =[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
```

and use the root logger to reference it:

```
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
```

hope this helped :)